# MomentJS Day diff dates only excluding time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way of comparing 2 dates without time with momentJS?

I've tried various formats, but can't seem to get it to work.

I have it working fine with dateTime:

```
var ExpiryDate = new Date("11/13/2014 11:13:00");
var daysDiff = moment(ExpiryDate).diff(moment(Date.now()), 'days');
```

I'm looking to get the result to be 14 days no matter what time of day.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to add a day based on time, then compare the timepart of two dates and add, if needed...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [startOf](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) function to remove the time components of both dates

```
moment(ExpiryDate).startOf('day').diff(moment(Date.now()).startOf('day'), 'days');
```

Comment: Note: This method alters the original date. For 'day' it literally sets minutes, seconds and hours for the *existing* object to 0 (so it is very fast). In this case you're creating a new object and altering it so there are no actual side effects but if you were to do `ExpiryDate.startOf('day')` without creating a new `moment` then it would change the original. Here's the implementation if you're curious : https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/497f918515ae6ab900f008f19523b1e4ae5e2450/src/lib/moment/start-end-of.js

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize to a function that prevents mutating the original objects:

```
/** Returns true if the first date is before the second one. */
function dateIsBefore(moment1: Moment, moment2: Moment): boolean {
  return moment1.clone().startOf('day') < moment2.clone().startOf('day')
}
```